# ASUS DSL-N10E firmware upgrade

Tags: wireless-networking, wireless-router, modem, firmware, tomato

I have a ASUS DSL-N10E modem\router with V2.1.15 APAC firmware. Is it upgradable to open-sourced firmwares like DD-WRT or Tomato (Tomato is preferred). Or is it hopeless? Plus, let's just say I try to upgrade it knowing it is not compatible. As predicted, the modem\router's some features don't work or it is totally bricked. If I have backuped the previous firmware, can I restore it to the previous firmware? What are the chances? Thanks in advance.

Comment: "can I restore it to the previous firmware?" - Does the router have a JTAG port?  Did you actually try putting an incompatible firmware on the device or is this just a "what if" question?

Comment: If you install open-source firmware and if it works at all, then you will lose the ADSL modem functionality of the unit.  At best you'll have an Ethernet switch and a wireless access point.

Comment: @Ramhound No, if you're talking about a physical port. And it is a "what if" question because I don't like to take risks. Plus, you are a very active user.

Comment: @sawdust Are there any open-sourced firmwares with ADSL modem functionality?

Comment: What does me being an active member have to do with my questions?  So your actual question is as simple as, "does the ASUS DSL-N10E, support Tomato?", is that correct?

Comment: [Tomato](http://www.polarcloud.com/) only supports specific devices, what devices it supports, is indicated on the front page of the website.  What devices DD-WRT supports is [documented](http://www.dd-wrt.com/site/support/router-database), which indicates your device is not supported.

Comment: Texas Instruments has ADSL hardware that has open source firmware.  It may be one of the few it not the only such ADSL HW.  See the RouterTech.org site at http://www.routertech.org/faq/firmware/compatible-routers/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Is it upgradable to open-sourced firmwares like DD-WRT or Tomato (Tomato is preferred).

According to Ramhound, neither DD-WRT or Tomato list your ASUS model as a supported device.
That unit is also not documented as using the Texas Instruments ADSL hardware that is supported by RouterTech.org.
So the obvious sources of firmware do not support that model.

> Or is it hopeless?

That will probably depend on how much free time you have, your capacity for learning, and how compliant ASUS is regarding open source licensing.
The [ASUS DSL-N10E User Manual](http://www.asus.com/support/Download/11/2/0/81/IonqBq0qSpplwUCD/8/) contains a copy of the GNU General Public License Version 2, indicating that this unit does use open source code (rather than proprietary code).  Under the terms of this license, you (as the purchaser of the device) can request a copy of the GPL'ed source code.  (Or there may be a web site where this code is already downloadable, as LG has for their TVs.)
It would then be up to you to figure out how to build and install this code, and to replace it with DD-WRT or Tomato modules.  Without embedded experience and board/HW documentation, this could be a daunting task.

Or wait for someone else to do this reverse engineering and development.

> If I have backuped the previous firmware, can I restore it to the previous firmware? What are the chances?

The answer is dependent on what was clobbered and what recovery capabilities are available.  A few SoCs (e.g. Marvell Kirkwood) have installers built into the ROM.  Most SoCs have a ROM program that can load a program over a serial connection for a tedious multi-stage re-installation.

If you're really curious, you could open up the unit and look for a serial console connection.  Typically it's a 3 or 4 pin header (which may not even be installed).  Once connected to the serial console, you can obtain a boot log and system information, and perhaps a shell prompt.

Comment: I googled 'Tomato firmware modem router' and I found a website named 'tomatousb.org' which says it is an enhanced version of Tomato and it says that it has full LAN/WAN/Wi-Fi support. Should I use that? Or is it fake?

Comment: Where does it state that your ADSL modem+router is a ***supported*** device?

Comment: @VaradMahashabde - post that link please